# Is it possible to send emails locally to user root

Tags: debian, email, postfix

I set up a mailing system in my Debian VPS. Everything works smoothly except for I can't send an email to user `root`.

There is a workaround to specify in `/etc/aliases` something like

`root: <some_other_user>`

Then all emails addressed to `root@<fqdn>` would go into `<some_other_user>@<fqdn>` mailbox.

From the security perspective it's even better but what I'm wondering about is whether there is a way to send emails to the user `root`.

So yes, is it possible technically with Postfix? If so, how can I do this?

UPDATE:

Here is `postfix.service` logs:

```
Apr 26 22:18:25 <hostname><fqdn> postfix/qmgr[2375]: 3905421760: from=<ddnomad@<fqdn>>, size=631, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 26 22:18:26 <hostname><fqdn> postfix/local[2429]: 3905421760: to=<mailuser@<fqdn>>, orig_to=<root@<fqdn>>, relay=local, delay=1.3, delays=0.21/0.01/0/1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
```

To my understanding it means that letter was sent successfully. But it never got delivered to `root`'s mailbox.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro in Postfix service logs it says that the email was delivered to a `procmail` command. I have not tried to send it with `procmail` only.

Comment: It is a `procmail`  "feature"....root emails go to the nobody user

Comment: If it's so where I can disable it (for testing purposes only)? Or it's not possible, is it? Yes, skimming through `man procmail` gives no information about such a "feature". Where can I read more about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

postfix uses `procmail`, to deliver email, and as `postfix` invokes `procmail` running as `nobody` for security reasons, emails sent to `root` will end up being sent to the `nobody` user.

[Debian mailing lists explain it better than me](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2000/02/msg00049.html), and suggest a work around:

> postfix's own delivery agent can deliver to root's mailbox, but
>   postfix will NEVER fork an external program (e.g. procmail) as root.
>   it either changes UID to the owner of the mail being delivered or if
>   that user is root, then it changes UID to nobody.
>
> so procmail gets run as nobody when delivering root's mail.
>
> i work around this by just symlinking /var/spool/mail/root to
>   /var/spool/mail/nobody - then i can read root's mail as root.
>   note
>   that this is NOT the recommended way of doing it - most people will
>   recommend that you direct root's mail to another user in /etc/aliases.

Further up in the thread, they also remember the `postfix` [FAQ about root mail](http://www.postfix.org/faq.html#root):

> If you use procmail (or some other command) for local mail delivery,
>   Postfix will not deliver mail as root. Instead, Postfix runs procmail
>   (or whatever) as nobody. Perhaps some day Wietse will trust Postfix
>   enough to run external commands as root. Solution: just like you're
>   not supposed to log in as root (except for unusual conditions), you're
>   not supposed to receive mail as root.
>
> Create a mail alias for root that forwards mail to a real user.